# My question is about the definition of a map called the "reduction map".

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ normal in $G$. I have read about a map $\alpha : G\rightarrow \frac{G}{N}$ called the reduction map mod $N$. I would love if someone could please explain this to me.

Is it just the map that sends all $g$ to $gN\in \frac{G}{N}$    ?

Comment: The reduction map goes from $G$ to $G/N$. It maps $g \in G$ to $gN$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\alpha: G \to G/N$?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry. I will edit it.

Comment: Martin B. Can you post that as an answer, so I may give you credit and show that I have received the answer. And thanks.

Comment: p.s. I searched for this on Google and found nothing on the first two pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the canonical group homorphism $G \to G/N$, $g \mapsto gN$ which actually belongs to the definition of the quotient group $G/N$. It is usually called the projection or quotient map.

Often the term "reduction map" is used for maps which are derived from the quotient map. For instance, there is a reduction map $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ which is induced by the ring quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.